# Failed to find ways to add up the values in /proc/meminfo to MemTotal

Tags: linux, memory

The following is the `/proc/meminfo` dump from one of the server I'm working on, and memory increase like crazy recently, triggering multiple system OOMs. When the free memory is really low situation, I captured the following dump. However, I could not really add the values up to the `MemTotal` here:

MemTotal - MemFree - Buffers - Cached - Active - Inactive - unevictable - Dirty - Writeback - Mapped - Shmem - kReclaimable - Slab - KernelStack - PageTables ~= 72GB

```
linux$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       528016144 kB
MemFree:         1130328 kB
MemAvailable:    4875944 kB
Buffers:            1888 kB
Cached:         30593868 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         308240008 kB
Inactive:       30496428 kB
Active(anon):   308160884 kB
Inactive(anon): 30357312 kB
Active(file):      79124 kB
Inactive(file):   139116 kB
Unevictable:          28 kB
Mlocked:              28 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:              5056 kB
Writeback:           188 kB
AnonPages:      308150576 kB
Mapped:         35963044 kB
Shmem:          30367440 kB
KReclaimable:    6440268 kB
Slab:           11568368 kB
SReclaimable:    6440268 kB
SUnreclaim:      5128100 kB
KernelStack:       67536 kB
PageTables:       904284 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    264008072 kB
Committed_AS:   85505936 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      533124 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:           178240 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:    527135128 kB
DirectMap2M:     4132864 kB
DirectMap1G:     7340032 kB
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: "*I could not really add the values ...*" -- Do you "*add*" by subtracting? Why are you not using plus signs instead of minus signs? Did you bother the look for and read any documentation as to what these entries mean? Maybe start with https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Comment: When you're done with your addition problem, you might want to search for the document titled `When Linux Runs Out of Memory` by Mulyadi Santosa :  "The conclusion is that **OOM** happens for two technical reasons: 1. No more pages are available in the VM. 2. No more user address space is available. 3. Both #1 and #2."